# Why do I have trouble staying within a narrow range of notes when singing songs that are toned down?

Tags: practice, self-learning, vocal-range, voice-training

My voice is very high, naturally, and carries a slight operatic tone. I'm unable to drop it. You can hear it in my voice even when I just talking or humming. I can produce an operatic sound with my lips closed. However, I like singing Disney songs for my own pleasure, which are toned down to be more personal and talkative. When I try to tone down my voice, the air gets trapped between my throat and chest and I can't breathe very well. It feels well below my range. It may sound strange but its like my voice can only go up, and up, and up. There's no coming down. When I stretch a note, it automatically gets higher until it softly wavers out in a vibrato sound. The air gets released from my mouth and I feel so much more comfortable in my throat and chest, much more able to breathe, letting the air go. Am I physically incapable of singing Disney songs within the range they are meant to be sang in? I make everything sound operatic, which is absurd. What's wrong with my voice?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "toned down". Do you mean "tuned down" or something to do with the style/volume/etc?

Comment: One thing you might try is taking 1-5 lessons with a voice teacher to get an authoritative answer

Comment: @the-baby-is-you I think it means "sung at a lower pitch."

Comment: "When I stretch a note, it automatically gets higher until it softly wavers out in a vibrato sound." Does this happen even when you try to sing a note that's comfortable for you?

Answer (score 3):

I have a very low voice and had some early classical voice training that had me singing with that "covered" operatic tone that involves a deep chest voice and a low larynx position. After taking just a few month's lessons from a coach using "speech level singing" (also called the "Seth Riggs method") I learned to place my larynx in a balanced position and access my head resonance. After that I was able to sing popular styles of music with a natural sound. I still have a big voice, but it doesn't sound operatic unless I make a conscious choice. For a female voice you might need to change something else, but I think that method should work well for anyone willing to put in the work.